# How to access the content of a memory address?

Tags: c++

### Question:

In **file1.cpp**, I save some data to memory with memory address 0x0364DF00.

In **file2.cpp**, how to access the content of the memory address (0x0364DF00)?

### What I tried

I tried adding some code to solve this problem, but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* address = (int*)0x0364DF00;
    cout << address(&address);
    return 0;
}
```

This is just an experiment. I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: You use the dereference operator `*` (`*address`) to access a memory address, but it won't work in your case. You can access hardware components through specific memory addresses on embedded systems or microcontrollers. On modern operating systems it doesn't work.

Comment: If file1.cpp and file2.cpp are compiled into the same program you can do more or less what you want, but if they are separate programs you have to use system-specific calls. On a modern desktop computer or server, programs are not allowed to see the storage used by other programs without jumping through complicated security hoops.

Comment: Handy reading: [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Also note that modern computers randomize where stuff is in memory to make it even harder for the malicious among us to run rampant.

Comment: [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) is a big topic.  There are lots of ways to do things, depending on your use case.  Using some scheme to send and receive messages is often favoured because it is easy to manage.  Shared memory can offer better performance, but is trickier to implement properly.

Comment: In some OS it's possible to create different kinds of memory that can be shared between different processes.  Even for that the memory address of that shared buffer might be different, like 0x10000000 in process A but 0x20000000 in process B.  With both of those set at run time, so changing each time you run process A or B.

Comment: **Memory addresses are lies the kernel tells you**. They are not "real", they do not correspond to any particular address in physical memory, they are virtual and importantly they cannot be shared between processes. Even if they could, any modern OS has protections that will actively prevent this kind of access from every happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using a concept called **shared memory**.

Using shared memory you could share say (as an example) a struct like the following:

```cpp
struct Data {
    std::atomic<int> counter;
};
```

Note that because you will be sharing data across different cores, you need to properly synchronize. In this case we use std::atomic.

You then need a mechanism to map this memory to a shared location, which is OS-specific but in general would consist in providing a file as a named-location for the memory and a size (to resize the file). Once opened the file can be memory-mapped and a pointer to a memory location is returned to the user.

In general the *producer* (or creator) is given the file name and size like this:

```cpp
// And this in file1.cpp
void child() {
    MappedFile file;
    if ( !file.open( "/tmp/file", 1024 ) ) return;
    Data* data = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(file.data());
    for ( unsigned j=0; j<=10; ++j ) {
        data->counter = j;
        ::usleep( 1000000 );
    }
}
```

Then the other process can then look at the file, get its size and memory map it on its entirety like in the following code. The pointer returned by the mapped location points to the same physical memory as the previous pointer. However, because these two functions are running on different process, their virtual mapping will be different and thus their numeric value will very likely be different too.

```cpp
// This can be in file2.cpp
void parent() {
    MappedFile file;
    while ( !file.open( "/tmp/file" ) ) {}
    Data* data = reinterpret_cast<Data*>( file.data() );
    int last = 0;
    while ( data->counter < 10 ) {
        if ( last!=data->counter ) {
            std::cout << "Counter:" << data->counter << std::endl;
            last = data->counter;
        }
    }
}
```

The internal implementation is OS-specific but on Linux it would look like the following. This is an example I wrote for testing so it's not production quality or even tested fully (but works for this example).

First define a class with an integer to hold the file descriptor, the file size and the shared memory location.

```cpp
struct MappedFile {
    MappedFile() {}
    ~MappedFile() { close(); }
private: 
    int _fid = -1;
    void* _addr = nullptr;
    std::size_t _mapsize = 0;
};
```

Then create one method to open/create the file with a given size. This is the "creator". It opens the file with the `O_CREAT` flag such that if the file does not exists, it is created. Then it truncates the file to the size provided, which is first rounded to a page size (typically 4k on Linux) - this is an `mmap()` requirement. Then the file is memory mapped and a pointer is returned to the user.

```cpp
    bool open( const std::string& filename, std::size_t filesize ) {
        int fid = ::open( filename.c_str(), 
            O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
        if ( fid<0 ) {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Could not create file " << filename << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        long mapsize = ((filesize-1)/PAGESIZE + 1 )*PAGESIZE;
        int res = ftruncate( fid, mapsize );
        if ( res!=0 ) {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Could not trucate file" << std::endl;
            ::close(fid);
            return false;
        }
        void* addr = mmap( nullptr, mapsize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fid, 0 );
        if ( addr==MAP_FAILED ) {
            std::cerr << "Could not memory map region" << std::endl;
            ::close(fid);
            return false;
        }
        close();
        _fid = fid;
        _addr = addr;
        _mapsize = mapsize;
        return true;
    }
```

Then there is another method that relies on the fact that the file is already created. Note that there is a possibility of a race condition where the consumer opens the file after it is created but before it is truncated to the correct size. For this reason, we check the file size to see if it is zero. The rest is the same with the exception that we do not resize the file.

```cpp
    bool open( const std::string& filename ) {
        struct stat sb;
        if ( stat( filename.c_str(), &sb ) != 0 ) {
            return false;        
        }
        size_t filesize = sb.st_size;
        if ( filesize == 0 ) return false;
        int fid = ::open( filename.c_str(), O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
        if ( fid<0 ) {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Could not open file " << filename << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        void* addr = mmap( nullptr, filesize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fid, 0 );
        if ( addr==MAP_FAILED ) {
            std::cerr << "Could not memory map region" << std::endl;
            ::close(fid);
            return false;
        }
        close();
        _fid = fid;
        _addr = addr;
        _mapsize = filesize;
        return true;
    }
```

Note that I say "producer" and "consumer" but both the processes have read-write access to the mapped memory.

Destroying the object is equal for both processes and as simple as unmapping the memory and closing the file.

```cpp
    void close() {
        if ( _addr!=nullptr ) {
            ::munmap( _addr, _mapsize );
            ::close(_fid);
        }
        _addr = nullptr;
        _fid = -1;
        _mapsize = 0;
    }
```

A sample driver for this test spawns a separate process with `fork()` and proceeds to share information

```cpp
int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0 ) child(); else parent();
}
```

This produces

```
Counter:1
Counter:2
Counter:3
Counter:4
Counter:5
Counter:6
Counter:7
Counter:8
Counter:9
Counter:10
```

full code on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/T8a5enzje

Comment: You are back on SO ! :D

Comment: @Soleil I tripped, fell on my chair and accidentally typed this answer